# Am I supposed to have access to "com.apple.TCC"?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

I was doing some snooping around on my MacBook Air after the update to macOS Mojave and noticed a folder that I have permission to view its contents that I don't have permission for on my iMac. The folder in question is "com.apple.TCC" under the Application Support folder, the path from the Finder is by selecting the following: `Macintosh HD -> Library -> Application Support`
[image: Show directory]

I was just poking around and noticed that the folder was inaccessible on the iMac and it had me wondering as to whether or not I should have access to it in the first place. I wasn't going around aimlessly deleting/modifying any of the files, I was just curiously looking at them and nothing more.

I find it quite strange that my MacBook is able to view the contents, but the iMac is not and was wondering if others can confirm if they can/cannot view its contents.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the TCC database stores the "privacy database": settings from System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy.

See https://eclecticlight.co/2017/01/09/controlling-privacy-in-macos-sierra/ and `man tccutil`.

The article says

> ... this is managed in a special TTC database, which is stored in the folder ~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC. There is also a master database stored at /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC, but you cannot open that folder, as only the system has that privilege.

On my iMac running High Sierra:

```
$ ls -ld /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC
drwx------  3 root    admin  102  4 Oct 11:15 /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC
drwx------  3 ashley  staff  102 29 Jun 16:13 /Users/ashley/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC
```

Note the different ownership: the one in `/Library` (= `Macintosh HD -> Library`) is owned by root, and the one in my home folder (`~/Library/Application Support` = `/Users/ashley/Library/Application Support`) is owned by me. Because the permissions are `drwx------` in both cases, only the owner can see into the folder... so when I look in Finder, the one in `/Library` has a "no entry" sign on it (because I'm not root), but I can open the one in my home folder, and see there is a file there named `TCC.db`.

I don't know why you see a difference between your MacBook Air and your iMac. In older times, I'd recommend you "repair permissions", but I believe that facility has gone away in the recent operating systems.

Comment: I checked my iMac and it had the same results that yours does: `~/Library/Application` has access while `/Library/Application` does not. . . However i am using a MacBook Air and im guessing that they have have different permissions for `/Library/Application` for their model as when i called Apple Support they confirmed that you can .open the "com.apple.TCC folder" in `/Library/Application`; i also checked the folder on the display models at an Apple store and they showed the same thing

Comment: FWIW, I've just tried using Carbon Copy Cloner to do a full backup of a Mac Mini running Mojave (10.14.5), and it's also unable to get at com.apple.TCC, even after my having granted full access to all the CCC apps and helpers.  There would seem to be some serious juju involving this thing.