# I can't delete folder com.apple.TCC

Tags: virus

The folder "com.apple.TCC" was created in /Library/Application Support at exactly the same time as a virus alert from ClamXAV. I had downloaded "GoToWebinar" as per the instructions in an e-mail sent from our known travel-agent. I've managed to delete all other files created at that time but, even with sudo from the command line, I can't do anything with the aforementioned folder - not even an"ls" command, "chmod". The folder is showing as having zero bytes but I'm concerned there may be something nasty lurking in there.

Comment: The reason why I'm suspicious about this folder is that it has a modified date/time of exactly the same time as the alert from ClamXAV - not  creation date, as I wrongly stated above.

Answer (score 3):

This is a legitimate folder required for macOS privacy settings.

[Am I supposed to have access to "com.apple.TCC"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339138/am-i-supposed-to-have-access-for-com-apple-tcc)

Randomly deleting system files and folders is never a good idea. Leave well alone.